# Что должен возвращать сервер после login операции?

Tags: typescript, redux, jwt, nestjs

**Я использую Аутентификацию на основе JWT токенов (access и refresh) и у меня сервер (после запроса на login) возвращает только access токен и не возвращает данные пользователя, соответственно я не могу получить данные о пользователе (по крайней мере я не знаю как их получить имея лишь лишь access token) , я не могу найти подробную документацию про это... Я склоняюсь к тому что вместе с access токеном нужно после login операции возвращать ещё и некоторые данные пользователя. Но я бы хотел услышать рекомендации от опытных и понять:

1. что должен возвращать сервер после login операции
2. Где хранить access token, refresh token я храню в cookie

На бэкенде использую nest js
На фронте: react, rtk (rtk query)
**

Comment: А что вы "зашиваете" в jwt токен?

Comment: Роль, username и id пользователя

Comment: Вы можете выполнить `jwt.decode` чтобы получить эти данные.